# C# exchange server get meeting room appointment list

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2007

I'm trying to work with `EWS Managed API` to get the meeting room list,
and for each room to see the appointment list for a week.

I saw [Get room lists by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643730(v=exchg.150).aspx)
And [Get appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx)

I've test the first link and I get 0 rooms.
Also for second link it gave the current user calendar but not meeting.

I need 3 things:

1) Get the meeting room list in my organization.
2) Get the meeting calendar for each room (for X days).
3) For each meeting, who organizes the meeting.

I cannot find the API for getting this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of searching and thanks to [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/67a186/exchange-development-finding-rooms-and-busyfree-status-with-suggestions-for-meeting/) 
I found an answer to question #1 and #2

1)  For getting all the meeting room in your organization:

```
 string filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(msExchRecipientDisplayType=7))";
 //Assembly System.DirectoryServices.dll
 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(filter);
 List<AttendeeInfo> rooms = new List<AttendeeInfo>();  
 foreach (SearchResult result in search.FindAll())
            {
                ResultPropertyCollection r = result.Properties;
                DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                // entry.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString() will bring the room name
                rooms.Add(new AttendeeInfo(entry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString().Trim()));                 
            }
```

2)  Get the meeting calendar for each room (for 2 days):

```
List<AttendeeInfo> attend = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
foreach (AttendeeInfo inf in rooms)
     {
       attend.Clear();
       attend.Add(inf.SmtpAddress);

       AvailabilityOptions options = new AvailabilityOptions();
       options.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 48;
       // service is ExchangeService object contains your authentication with exchange server
       GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attend, new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)), AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions, options);

        foreach (AttendeeAvailability attendeeAvailability in results.AttendeesAvailability)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (attendeeAvailability.ErrorCode == ServiceError.NoError)
                    {
                        foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarEvent calendarEvent in
                        attendeeAvailability.CalendarEvents)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Calendar event");
                            Console.WriteLine(" Starttime: " + calendarEvent.StartTime.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine(" Endtime: " + calendarEvent.EndTime.ToString());
                            if (calendarEvent.Details != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(" Subject:" + calendarEvent.Details.Subject);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

About question #3, it's not simple to get this information because it's private information and as regular user you don't have a permission to see it.

Comment: Getting rooms as shown only works if the Exchange is on-prem and tied to the domain.